# Clean up and normalize CSV commas (flat file)

Tags: csv, awk, normalize

I have a list that goes like this:

```
info1, info2, info3, info4, info5, info6
info1, info2, info3, info6
info1, info4, info6
info1, info2, info4, info5
```

And so on...
I need to work with what would be *info4* and *info5*, (for example, of course), for which I'd need to normalize the data; is there any method I could use in order to achieve this?

I'd highly appreciate any advice.

Comment: edit your question to show what the normalized output you are expecting for your sample data. Good luck.

Comment: and don't use "info1, info2, etc." for every field in every line - show some unique input in all fields so we know whats coming from where when you post your desired output.

Comment: You need to show what your expected output is, and identify how you can look at a line with three values and determine that the second is 'info4' and tell us what to do with the absence of 'info5'.  Do you need to keep 'info1' or anything to identify the source lines?  Until you add this information, this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy enough to use `awk` you could do something like this:

```
awk -F, '{print $4 FS $5}' inputfile.txt
```

Comment: IFS is the name of a shell variable, awk has FS and OFS but no IFS.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Comment: @robert Your answer looks more like a comment. Please update it to be an answer.